# Z3Python: ForAll causes my code hangup, or returns Unsat, why?

Tags: z3, z3py

I am still struggling with the problem of findiong `a` value so that `a * b == b` with all value of `b`. The expected result is `a == 1`. I have two solutions below.

**(A) I implemented this with `ForAll` quantifier in below code (correct me if there is a solution without using any quantifier). The idea is to prove `f` and `g` are equivalent.**

```
from z3 import *

a, b, a1, tmp1 = BitVecs('a b a1 tmp1', 32)

f = True
f = And(f, tmp1 == b)
f = And(f, a1 == a * tmp1)

g= True
g = And(g, a1 == b)

s = Solver()
s.add(ForAll([b, tmp1, a1], f == g))

if s.check() == sat:
    print 'a =', s.model()[a]
else:
    print 'Unsat'
```

However, this simple code runs forever without giving back result. I think that is because of the `ForAll`. Any idea on how to fix the problem?

**(B) I tried again with another version. This time I dont prove two formulas to be equivalent, but put them all into one formula `f`.** Logically, I think this is true, but please correct me if I am wrong here:

```
from z3 import *

a, b, a1, tmp = BitVecs('a b a1 tmp', 32)

f = True
f = And(f, tmp == b)
f = And(f, a1 == a * tmp)
f = And(f, a1 == b)

s = Solver()
s.add(ForAll([b, a1], f))

if s.check() == sat:
    print 'a =', s.model()[a]
else:
    print 'Unsat'
```

This time the code does not hang, but immediately returns 'Unsat'. Any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct formulation of your problem provides the answer you were expecting: http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/N07sW

The versions you propose use auxiliary variables, a1, tmp, tmp1 and you
use universal quantification over these variables. This does not correspond
to the formula you intended.

Comment: Nikolaj, actually the problem I am trying to solve is not that simple formula "a * b == b", but belong to a broader problem. The fact is that the formula I am given to solve always have those auxiliary variables (a1, tmp, etc). Do you have any suggestion to fix the original code (A) and (B), please?